# Maven Configuration issue - settings.xml

Tags: spring, maven-2

Few jars are taken from my repository successfully. This particular jar (failed, see below) needs to be from Maven central Repo but it is seeing to download it from my repo where this jar is not present. I feel that my configuration in settings.xml is wrong. My major doubt is in mirror configuration.

> Could not find artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:1.4.0.RELEASE in my domain http://w3.maven.mydomain.com/nexus/content/repositories/domain)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">

<pluginGroups></pluginGroups>

<proxies></proxies>

<servers>
 <server>
        <id>myrepo</id>
        <username>myname</username>
        <password>****</password>
        <configuration></configuration>
    </server>
</servers>
<mirrors>
<mirror>
   <id>maven2</id>
   <name>maven2</name>
   <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
   <mirrorOf>maven</mirrorOf>
</mirror>   
  <mirror>
   <id>myrepo</id>
   <name>repo TPS</name>
   <url>http://w3.maven.mydomain.com/nexus/content/repositories/domain</url>
   <mirrorOf>central</mirrorOf>
 </mirror>
</mirrors>
<profiles></profiles>
</settings>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try adding below in your pom.xml

```
<repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
```

Comment: I'm able to resolve by removing the mirror and adding it as a repository. Anyway, thanks for your suggestion.